# Как поместить этот код в одну строчку

Tags: python

Нужно поместить этот код внутрь функции print

```
items = ["lawyer", "attorney", "prosecutor"]
new_list = []
for i in items:
    i = i + " is related to legal affairs"
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: list comprehension вам в помощь

Comment: А как в инициализировать переменную items внутри print()?

Comment: list comprehension это лишь пол беды

Answer (score 2):

```
print([i + " is related to legal affairs" for i in ["lawyer", "attorney", "prosecutor"]])
```